# Bitwise calculations in oracle over a large result set

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following scenario that is trivialized in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32d53/2):

Within my database I will be processing a large result set (100 million+) records at a time and need to merge together permissions that are represented as numeric values.  A bitwise OR is the aggregation that will be used.  My question is, what is the most efficient way to ensure that in the fiddle the `Steve` entry returns a tuple that looks like this:

```
name     permissions   
Steve    23 --(bit_or)
```

I know the primary issue is keeping track of the times I have seen `Steve` but I cannot deduce an efficient manner to handle this.  The preference is that this is done in the database so that a `materialized view` can handle the post-calculation result set.

**Question**

> Aggregating using a bitwise or doesn't sound appealing to me. Can't
>   you create a separate column with that mask already applied?

**Response**

> that is what gets stored in the materialized view. I have to calculate
>   it somewhere. The issue is specifically that this is a data warehouse
>   application that is constantly being fed data and these permissions
>   need to be updated fairly frequently based upon the caching strategy
>   that is utilized.

Comment: Aggregating using a bitwise or doesn't sound appealing to me. Can't you create a separate column with that mask already applied?

Comment: @GolezTrol that is what gets stored in the materialized view.  I have to calculate it somewhere.  The issue is specifically that this is a data warehouse application that is constantly being fed data and these permissions need to be updated fairly frequently based upon the caching strategy that is utilized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient solution is *probably* to run direct SQL aggregates. Since permission is finite, there is a given number of individual permissions (N). You could decompose each permission in N columns, aggregate (using `MAX`) and reassemble the permissions after:

```
p1 = sign(BitAnd(permissions, 2^0))
p2 = sign(BitAnd(permissions, 2^1))
...
P1 = MAX(p1)
P2 = MAX(P2)
...

Permissions = 2^0 * P1 + 2^1 * P2 + ... + 2^(N-1) * PN
```

But that [would be tedious](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cdb73/3) and you would have to rewrite your query when you add new permissions:

```
SQL> select name,
  2           power(2, 0) * MAX(sign(BitAnd(permissions, power(2, 0))))
  3         + power(2, 1) * MAX(sign(BitAnd(permissions, power(2, 1))))
  4         + power(2, 2) * MAX(sign(BitAnd(permissions, power(2, 2))))
  5         + power(2, 3) * MAX(sign(BitAnd(permissions, power(2, 3))))
  6         + power(2, 4) * MAX(sign(BitAnd(permissions, power(2, 4))))
  7         + power(2, 5) * MAX(sign(BitAnd(permissions, power(2, 5))))
  8         + power(2, 6) * MAX(sign(BitAnd(permissions, power(2, 6))))
  9         + power(2, 7) * MAX(sign(BitAnd(permissions, power(2, 7))))
 10         + power(2, 8) * MAX(sign(BitAnd(permissions, power(2, 8))))
 11            permissions
 12    from cats
 13   group by name;

NAME            PERMISSIONS
--------------- -----------
Carl                     15
Steve                    23
```

Instead I suggest you write your own user-defined aggregate (inspired by this [post by Tom Kyte](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEoQFjAD&url=http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402&ei=iHOiUPCqI6LU0QW594GADw&usg=AFQjCNEHIx6szttJBLhtj5nuP_KntO7LUQ) -- tested on 9ir2):

```
SQL> create or replace type bin_agg_type as object
  2  (
  3     total NUMBER,
  4
  5     static function
  6          ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT bin_agg_type )
  7          return number,
  8
  9     member function
 10          ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT bin_agg_type ,
 11                               value IN NUMBER)
 12          return number,
 13
 14     member function
 15          ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN bin_agg_type ,
 16                                 returnValue OUT NUMBER,
 17                                 flags IN number)
 18          return number,
 19
 20     member function
 21          ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT bin_agg_type,
 22                             ctx2 IN bin_agg_type)
 23          return number
 24  );
 25  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type body bin_agg_type
  2  is
  3
  4  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT bin_agg_type )
  5  return number
  6  is
  7  begin
  8      sctx := bin_agg_type ( 0 );
  9      return ODCIConst.Success;
 10  end;
 11
 12  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT bin_agg_type ,
 13                                       value IN NUMBER)
 14  return number
 15  is
 16  begin
 17      self.total := self.total + value - BitAND(self.total, value);
 18      return ODCIConst.Success;
 19  end;
 20
 21  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN bin_agg_type ,
 22                                         returnValue OUT NUMBER,
 23                                         flags IN number)
 24  return number
 25  is
 26  begin
 27      returnValue := total;
 28      return ODCIConst.Success;
 29  end;
 30
 31  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT bin_agg_type ,
 32                                     ctx2 IN bin_agg_type )
 33  return number
 34  is
 35  begin
 36      self.total := self.total+ctx2.total - BitAND(self.total, ctx2.total);
 37      return ODCIConst.Success;
 38  end;
 39
 40
 41  end;
 42  /

Type body created.

SQL> CREATE or replace
  2  FUNCTION BitOr_Agg(input NUMBER)
  3  RETURN NUMBER
  4  PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING bin_agg_type ;
  5  /

Function created.
```

Let's call it:

```
SQL> SELECT name, bitor_agg(permissions) from cats group by name;

NAME            BITOR_AGG(PERMISSIONS)
--------------- ----------------------
Carl                                15
Steve                               23
```

I would be curious to know which one is the fastest.

Comment: I am going to run this right now and see the timing i get, on large result sets.

Comment: I will run both as I have the data set to confirm

Comment: The second approach is vastly superior to the expanded sql

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Link](http://radino.eu/2008/05/31/bitwise-or-aggregate-function/) to a blog that has an implementation of a Bitwise OR aggregate function in Oracle.